# How to redirect URL if it contains "?"?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've come up with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)?(.*)$ http://google.com [P]
```

but this approach works for addresses without `?` - it is meant to work only for those with `?`.

When I try to escape `?` with `/?` - I have redirect no matter if URL has `?` or doesn't,

when I escape `?` with `\?` - I end up with no redirect at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` is part of `QUERY_STRING` and not `REQUEST_URI`, and so you cannot check it directly in the rule itself.

You can check for the presence of the `?` by checking either `QUERY_STRING` or `THE_REQUEST`:

```bsh
# Check that QUERY_STRING is not empty:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^ http://google.com/ [P]
```

```bsh
# Check for the presence of a question mark in THE_REQUEST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s+(.+)\?(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://google.com/ [P]
```